# AES Encryption of Data during MySQL Master - Slave Replication

Tags: mysql, aes, database-replication

I need to encrypt some data on MySQL slave and using AES_Encrypt for the same. Is it possible to encrypt it while replicating it from the Master database?

Using MySQL 5.6

Comment: Without encrypting it on the master?  Do you actually need the data on the slave at all?

Comment: Master will get unencrypted data from different sources. I am then replicating it to slave so that it is accessible for reporting and analysis. But some of the fields have sensitive information and it's access needs to be restricted. So I am hoping to encrypt it during replication.

Comment: Access needs to be restricted?  Or eliminated?  There's a way to prevent certain columns from replicating at all in MySQL... and there's a possible solution available in MariaDB 10.1, but not in MySQL.  (Only the slave would need to run MariaDB in this case, the master could still be running MySQL).  Do either of those sound useful?

Comment: This is definitely useful, but not helpful for my requirements :-)

Access needs to be restricted so that is someone with appropriate use-case and approvals require unmasked data, then the encryption key could be shared with them.
Nonetheless, thanks a lot for your help.! Please let me know your inputs if I could do something else for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL replication, when using `binlog_format=STATEMENT`, triggers fire on the master and again on the slave, but there is no specific requirement that the triggers be defined identically on the master and slave, or that triggers be provisioned on both.

I say there is no *specific* requirement, because it is not enforced.  If you want the data to be identical on master and slave -- as is almost always the case in a replicated environment -- then yes, the triggers have to be defined identically on both servers... but it is possible to customise the slave triggers -- and one way of doing it would be to define `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers on the slave that encrypted the columns before inserts and updates.

This does require `STATEMENT` replication, which I don't use because it is more delicate and some statements cannot be deterministically replicated in `STATEMENT` mode.

This would require extra care to ensure that master and slave are always consistent, and would require custom tools since standard table comparison tools would consider master and slave tables to be different.

---

With `binlog_format=ROW`, any triggers defined on the slave are ignored for replicated events, because they would be redundant -- the changes done by the triggers on the master will already be replicated to the slave as row events, and executing the triggers on the slave would not have the correct result.  Row-based replication uses raw row images, so is always deterministic, unlike statement based replication.

The MariaDB team recognizes that there may be cases where identical data sets are not the objective, such as where you might want to build denormalized query tables on the slave, so in MariaDB 10.1, they introduced a feature to allow slaves to fire triggers for row-based events.  This might also be a viable solution, if your master is not using statement-based replication.  It does not appear to require the master to run MariaDB, only the slave.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/running-triggers-on-the-slave-for-row-based-events/

---

It is also possible to create accounts that cannot access all columns, since the MySQL permissions model allows grants to be made at the server, database, table, and column level.  Without permission to access a column, you won't see it, in spite of it being there.

---

Arguably, though, if the data is sensitive, the most correct solution would be to encrypt it on the master.